# Angular: Google maps directive loaded in another Modal directive stays blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am fairly new to angular but I have hit a roadblock when trying to load a 'google maps' directive inside another directive.

The following is a 'modal-view' directive in which I load a form..

```
    angular.module('test').directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
              '<div class="modal-header">' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: 'element',
      replace:true,
      scope:false,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        ...
      }
    };
});
```

Next up, this is the google maps directive...

```
    angular.module('test').directive('googleMaps', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    template:"<div></div>",
    replace:true,
    transclude: true,
    scope:false,
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
      window.onload = function() {
        scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });

        scope.map.addListener('click', function() {
          alert("Click!");
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

If I simply load the map directive normally, the map appears all well and good. The problem occurs when I try to load the map in the other directive, like so...

```
//modal directive        
<modal title="{{title}}" visible="showModal">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <form class="dropzone" dropzone="dropzoneConfig"></form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form role="form" name="userForm"  ng-submit="addPerson(person)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="person.name" required />
            </div>

    //Maps directive
            <google-maps id="map" class="form-group"></google-maps>

          </form>

        </modal>
```

At this point, the frame gets loaded with the google logo, but the map is not loaded, the grey background stays displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this! Thanks

Comment: Be sure that `googleMaps` directive not replace `<google-maps id="map" class="form-group"></google-maps>` just with `"<div></div>"` and `id="map" ` still exists.

Comment: The html is generated correctly, there is also the google logo at the bottom left of the div.. but it still displays a grey background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to shaishab roy's '$timeout' suggestion, I found out that I was trying to load the map in a hidden div. The solution was to initialise the map when the modal view is shown. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If normally displayed well then it may angular `digest` problem. you can try initialize map in `$timeout` function and no need to `document.onload`. you should inject `$timeout` before use.

like:

```
angular.module('test').directive('googleMaps', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:"<div></div>",
        replace:true,
        transclude: true,
        scope:false,
        link:function(scope, element, attrs){
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                });

                scope.map.addListener('click', function() {
                    alert("Click!");
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks for this, but unfortunately I got the same result.. Do I have to configure the "$timeout" variable, or do I have to import a certain file to use this dependency?

Comment: inject `$timeout` in your directive. added in above code `directive('googleMaps', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) ....` and can try by set some time in `$timeout` function `$timeout( function() { //code }, 5000);`

Comment: also you can use `element[0]` instead of `document.getElementById(attrs.id)`

Comment: Thank you Roy, I figured out what is happening.. I was loading the map in a div that was hidden. What I did now is I initialised the map when the modal view is shown. Thanks for your help :)